# Make the user enter the credentials for specific pages

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

In my `Grails 3.3.10` application I'm using `Spring security plugin` , for a specific pages that got critical information I need the user to enter the credentials again although this user logged in before while entering to the application, Any ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this in your `application.groovy`. For example

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/sensitivepage/**',       access: ['ROLE_USER', 'isFullyAuthenticated()']]
]
```

Anything under `/sensitivepage/` will require re-authentication.

It's explained in the [Spring Security Documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/4.0.x/index.html#requestMappings).

Comment: already the user authenticated while login to the application , now I need the user to login again to see or change the sensitive data, like Google , you are already in the Gmail but when you try to change the password for example it asks you again to enter the password. This is what I want to achieve

Comment: SShehab, some sites will give you the impression that’s happening because you’ve been logged in so long and are operating under the benefit of a remember-me cookie which is keeping you authenticated but not fullyAuthenticated under the spring security rules. 

That aside, if you want to force a user to log in all the time regardless just pop a modal and prompt the user with input fields and validate in the backend using the springSecurityService.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a filter chain for endpoints that do need to log in again and register a custom filter. In that filter, you can revoke the existing token. Make these endpoints secure so that if a request comes without token then it would redirect the user to the login page.

Here is a sample code for your reference: (Please note that I haven't tried this scenario, it just a thought that I'm sharing here.)

```
<bean id="reauthenticateFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="reauthenticateResourceRequestMatcher"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <list>
            <ref bean="reauthenticateFilter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This is how you can register your custom filter chain.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="reauthenticateFilterChain"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```